# CSS and word wrapping

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a "progress breadcrumb" on my site. Most of my CSS experience is with cargo-culting other people's, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

**Update**: Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4reM/5/

My CSS looks like:

```
div.progtrckr-table {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div.progtrckr-table div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 2%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
div.progtrckr-table div.progtrckr-done,
div.progtrckr-table div.progtrckr-doing {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid yellowgreen;
}
div.progtrckr-table div.progtrckr-todo {
    color: silver; 
    border-bottom: 4px solid silver;
}
div.progtrckr-table div:after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0";
}
div.progtrckr-table div:after {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -1.7em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
div.progtrckr-table div.progtrckr-done:after {
    content: "\2713";
    color: white;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    height: 1.2em;
    width: 1.2em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1.2em;
}
div.progtrckr-table div.progtrckr-doing:after {
    content: "\039F";
    color: yellowgreen;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: -1.1em;
}
div.progtrckr-table div.progtrckr-todo:after {
    content: "\039F";
    color: silver;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: -1.1em;
}
```

and my html looks like:

```
<div class="progtrckr-table"> 
  <div class="progtrckr-done">Pickup/Delivery Options</div>
  <div class="progtrckr-done">Check Availability</div>
  <div class="progtrckr-doing">Reserve Boards</div>
  <div class="progtrckr-todo">Checkout</div>
</div>
```

On a nice wide screen, it looks great:
[image: Wide Screen]
Narrow the screen down to just before one of the texts wants to wrap, and it starts looking wrong (the dots don't line up):
[image: not lining up]
A few more pixels narrower so "Pickup/Delivery Options" word-wraps and it starts looking good again:
[image: looking better]

The only clue I have as to what is going wrong is that when I select the four divs in Chrome's Developer Tools, beforehand it tells me that the divs are 85x48, 84x48, 84x48, 84x48, during the not-lining-up phase, they are 84x62.797, 84x63, 84x63, 84x63, and when they're lined up all four are the same size again. If I shrink it to a point where one of the other divs isn't matching up with the dots, the size of that div is the one that has a fractional size rather than a whole number.

Can somebody tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: I just did `bottom: -1.3em;` for `div.progtrckr-table div:after` and [**it seems to be working fine**](http://jsfiddle.net/FLyYt/1/) for me on IE & Chrome.

Comment: @srvikram13 not for me - I still get breakpoints where the dot is a bit above the line, shrink it a few pixels and suddenly it's below the line.

Comment: Hmmm. I made the fiddle and it's nowhere near as prominent in the fiddle is it is in my site.

Comment: Possibly some issue of overriding css?

Comment: Looks that way - I added some of the things that Developer Tools tells me are also being applied to the fiddle, and now you can see the problem.

Comment: @srvikram13 - you were correct about the overriding CSS. I added `line-height: normal;` to the `div.progtrckr-table div` block and set the `bottom: -1.3em;` as you stated above, and now it's working right. See http://jsfiddle.net/Z4reM/8/ - If you want to make that your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It's OK. I'm glad I could help.